# How can I ensure that each jenkins job is placed in its respective folder, similar to implementing GitFlow in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

Seeking for your help. I want my branch job feature/HHA-1 to put in feature folder. And every repository that has feature in branch name will be on feature folder e.g feature/HMY-1 (this is from another repo). And when feature/HHA-1 is in the folder feature the name will be just HHA-1.
[image]

[image]